# C# Method overloading using dynamic params

Tags: c#, dynamic, parameters, polymorphism

I'm trying to write a tool for serialization of values. And I was hoping to get some nice syntax working.....

```
            float f = 9999.0f;
            ByteSerializer s = new ByteSerializer ();
            s.Write(f);
```

Where the params of Write() could be anything and any number:

```
    public void Write (params dynamic[] objects)
    {

        for (int i =0;i<objects.Length;i++) {

            byteList.AddRange (GetBytes (objects[i]));

        }
    }
```

GetBytes() should now be called according to the type of the object that was passed:

```
    public  byte[] GetBytes ( object v)
    {
    //Shouldn't actually do anything since it's a dummy
        return new byte[0];
    }


    public  byte[] GetBytes ( System.Single v)
    {
    //Why is this not called?

        return BitConverter.GetBytes (v);

    }
```

But it will always go straight for the method that takes an object as parameter. 
I initially tried (params object[]) as method parameters and found this behaviour to be rather obvious. But why does dynamic[] behave the same?

objects[i].GetType() reports a System.Single so what's going on here? Is what I am trying to do just not possible?

Comment: I checked you code and i cant find behaviur which you described. For numeric types if conversion is possible (neverthless if I create variable as a dynamic or not) GetBytes for Single type is called. For case when conversion is not possible or type is not numeric object version is called. Can you give a example of situation which you described?

Comment: Wait...this works for you? `float f = 9999.0f; Write (f);  void Write (object v)
 {
 GetBytes(v);
 }     public void GetBytes ( object v)
    {
Console.WriteLine("Object");
    }


    public  void  GetBytes ( System.Single v)
    {

  
Console.WriteLine("Single");

    } `

Comment: Yes I write code like this and it works for me.

Comment: Do you have multiple overloads of `Write`? I agree with Krzysztof, this should work. See my answer for an example.

Comment: This must be unsupported by Unity/Mono then. I really did not think the fact I was using Unity3D would be of any significance for this issue. Thanks for all the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method overloading relies on knowing at **compile time** the types of all the arguments. Here, you can't know the argument types at compile time - because it's `dynamic` - so the compiler uses the lowest common type - which is `object`. The difference between `object` and `dynamic` is that `dynamic` allows late binding syntax - but that doesn't help you here.

If you want to call `GetBytes` for the correct types, you need to use [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29). Specifically, you want to use [GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find an overload of `GetBytes` that matches the type of each argument, and then call it. with [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something like this(not tested):

```
byteList.AddRange (GetType()
        .GetMethod("GetBytes", new Type[objects[i].GetType()])
        .Invoke(null, new object[objects[i]]));
```

Comment: `byteList.AddRange (GetType().GetMethod("GetBytes",new Type[] { objects[i].GetType() }).Invoke(this,new object[]{objects[i]}));` Worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason this shouldn't work with `dynamic` exactly as you described. One of the primary features of the DLR is to do at runtime what would have been done at compile time if the types had been known then. For example, the following program:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteItems("a string", (byte)1, 3f, new object());
    }

    private static void WriteItems(params dynamic[] items)
    {
        foreach(dynamic item in items)
        {
            Write(item);
        }
    }

    private static void Write(byte b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write byte: {0}", b);
    }

    private static void Write(float f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write Single: {0}", f);
    }

    private static void Write(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write string: {0}", s);
    }        

    private static void Write(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write object: {0}", o);
    }
}
```

Produces the output:

> Write string: a string
>   Write byte: 1
>   Write Single: 3
>   Write object: System.Object

Answer (score 0):

The `dynamic` type behaves like the `object` type. The only difference is that for `dynamic` the compiler does no type checking (so you can avoid compiler errors when working e.g. with COM).

What you intend, can be done anyway. But you must take the long road and do an explicit typechecking/cast in your `for` loop (a long but simple `switch`/`case` construct).

HTH Thomas

Comment: Okay so that explains why they behave the same. Type switching is something I do not want to do (anymore). I initially had the GetBytes() methods set up as extension methods to the actual type, but I already noticed that this is not possible the way I'm calling them. So instead of statically calling them for no real reason, I made them instance methods.